# Why are stress intensity units MPa√m

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, aerospace-engineering

The units of stress intensity are usually taken as MPa√m. Cracks are usually measured in (mm), could someone please explain why this convention is used an not consistent SI units

Comment: because the inverse root of the crack length is what matters.  We measure height in meters but gravity is a function of the inverse height squared.  it's just the wqay it works.

Comment: This unit is surely one of the weirdest, but that is how nature works. If you have a specimen with a crack which is under stress, the crack can enlarge, thus creating new surfaces which have higher energy than interior. The energy for that comes from stress relaxation during crack propagation. If you equate these energies, you will end up with units like this. For more information, check out [Griffith's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_mechanics#Griffith's_criterion).

Comment: As I remember Griffith and others calculated stress at the crack tip and the result was in units of psi X square root inches. The material property is fracture toughness. Wikipedia has a good explanation as  LEFM ( linear elastic fracture mechanics.)

Comment: The other primary author is Irwin.